# Mongo DB. Failed to update a record

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql

I face an interesting issue: can't update some value in Mongo DB from shell. Actually this happens on some other Mongo DB. On my local DB w/ the same DB schema the same update commands work perfectly. It seems that after some manipulation(s) db became read-only. The `rs.status()` command returns `not running with --replSet`. Mongo version is '2.4.9'.

Where should i look at to resolve the issue?
Thanks!

UPD. It seems such things happen only on some collections. Other collections in db work fine

UPD2. The update cmd i use is the following: `db.userprofile.update({login: 'admin'}, {$set:{'filter.table.login':'a111'}})`. It returns no messages at all. But on another MongoDB of the same version and w/ the same schema it works w/o problems and executes update.

UPD3. The command `db.getUsers()` returns me this: `TypeError: Property 'getUsers' of object admin is not a function` regardless i use admin db or my own db.

UPD4. It seems i found the place where the issue can be. So far i found that i can modify other documents in the collection. So i had problems in one or two documents only. One of such documents looks like this (a snippet):

```
"filter" : {
    "" : {
        "domain" : null,
        "type" : null
    },
    "table1" : {
        "pageNumber" : 1,
        "page1" : 10
    },
    "table2" : {
        "domain" : null,
        "login" : "",
        "page1" : 1,
        "page2" : 10
    },
```

For some reasons an empty value ("") was saved as a key. I assume that this empty value can be the root of such error. But why Mongo driver didn't complain about such situation during insert?

Comment: 1: How do you mean, you can't update some value? Do you get an error message back, for example? 2: Have you checked the user permissions?

Comment: Could be the other MongoDB is an older server version which does not support an update operator that you are using.  You really need to provide more information.

Comment: hi! Thanks for your suggestions. i updated the description. What else information can be useful?